# Variable updating based on temp variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to understand a strange thing in Python. I created a dictionary in Python, assigned the dictionary values to a temporary variable, and then cleared all the values in the temporary variable. Strangely, the values in the dictionary also got cleared. What could be the reason behind it ?

For example, in cases where I do not want to affect the main variable, and just do something in the temporary variable, this will never work. Is there a workaround ?

Below is the steps that I tried to execute

```
dict = {'random' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
data = dict['random']
data
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data.clear()
dict
{'random': []}
```

Comment: TLDR: There is only *one single* object ``[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`` created in this code. It is known to Python both as ``dict['random']`` and ``data``. You must explicitly copy it if you want to create a second object with the same value.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi : Thank you for the answer. Now I managed to fix the problem with the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `data = dict['random']` just binds "data" to the array inside "dict", it doesn't copy it.

Look at [Python Copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) which explains it in a bit more depth and how to actually copy rather than bind.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks